# Dagger - error: [Dagger/MapKeys] The same map key is bound more than once - Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am suing from dagger in my project but get me bellow error:

```
error: [Dagger/MapKeys] The same map key is bound more than once for java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>>
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<dagger.android.DaggerApplication> {
                ^
      @Binds @dagger.multibindings.IntoMap @dagger.multibindings.ClassKey(com.Courses.CoursesActivity.class) dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?> com.Courses.module.CoursesActivityProvider_CoursesActivity.bindAndroidInjectorFactory(com.Courses.module.CoursesActivityProvider_CoursesActivity.CoursesActivitySubcomponent.Factory)
      @Binds @dagger.multibindings.IntoMap @dagger.multibindings.ClassKey(com.Courses.CoursesActivity.class) dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?> com.di.ActivityBuilder_BindCoursesActivity.bindAndroidInjectorFactory(com.di.ActivityBuilder_BindCoursesActivity.CoursesActivitySubcomponent.Factory)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector(injectorFactoriesWithClassKeys, …)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<java.lang.Object> is injected at
          dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.androidInjector
      com.Courses.CoursesActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.di.AppComponent → com.di.ActivityBuilder_BindCoursesActivity.CoursesActivitySubcomponent]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.di.AppComponent → com.di.ActivityBuilder_BindCoursesActivity.CoursesActivitySubcomponent → com.Courses.module.CoursesActivityProvider_CoursesActivity.CoursesActivitySubcomponent]
```

Here is `AppScoped`:

```
@Scope
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class AppScoped
```

And `CoursesActivityScope`:

```
@Scope
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CoursesActivityScope
```

And `ActivityBuilder`:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [CoursesActivityProvider::class])
    abstract fun bindCoursesActivity(): CoursesActivity?
}
```

And `AppComponent`:

```
@AppScoped
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication?> {
    fun inject(app: App?)
    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication?)
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application?): Builder?

        fun build(): AppComponent?
    }
}
```

And `AppModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideContext(application: Application?): Context?
}
```

And `App`:

```
import dagger.android.support.DaggerApplication;
@AppScoped
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AppComponent? {
        val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            ?.build()
        appComponent!!.inject(this)
        return appComponent
    }
}
```

And here is my `Activity`:

```
@CoursesActivityScope
class CoursesActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(){
  ......
}
```

But get me above error.

Answer (score 3):

I edited this `class` to:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @CoursesActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [CoursesActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun bindCoursesActivity(): CoursesActivity?
}
```